# Regex to remove all "@[x]"

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to remove all **@[x]** present in a string
Where **x** can be any string.
For example @[title]

Comment: "any string"? Excluding other square brackets? Also, what have you tried that didn't work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@\[[^\]]*\]`?

As in:

```
  String s = "asda @[asdagf] dsgfdg";

  System.out.println(s.replaceAll("@\\[[^\\]]*\\]",""));
```

will print out:

```
asda  dsgfdg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String original = "Hello @[world]!";
String replaced = original.replaceAll("@\\[.*?\\]", "");
// replaced = "Hello !"`enter code here`
```